# awk manipulation of a file

Tags: awk

I have a file which is the output of several commands piped. Something like this

```
command1 input.txt| command2 | command3 | input file
```

The file is tab-separated

After command 3, my input file looks like this

```
chr6    116732135   116741866   116732135   116732368   116741505   116741866   +   0.79    0.51    0.97    0.77    0.48    0.97    0.02    0.37    'chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.A.withRI','chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.up_chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.dn'    (0,0):10,(1,0):147,(1,1):1  0:148   (0,0):36,(1,0):161,(1,1):3  0:163,1:1   chr6    +   116732136,116732136 116741866,116741866 gene_id "ENSG00000196911.10"; transcript_id "ENST00000368564.6"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "KPNA5"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "KPNA5-202"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000357552.1"; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS5111.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000015448.4"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000041967.2";
chr6    116732135   116741866   116732135   116732368   116741505   116741866   +   0.79    0.51    0.97    0.77    0.48    0.97    0.02    0.37    'chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.A.withRI','chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.up_chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.dn'    (0,0):10,(1,0):147,(1,1):1  0:148   (0,0):36,(1,0):161,(1,1):3  0:163,1:1   chr6    +   116732136,116732136 116741866,116741866 gene_id "ENSG00000196911.10"; transcript_id "ENST00000356348.6"; gene_type "protein_coding"; gene_name "KPNA5"; transcript_type "protein_coding"; transcript_name "KPNA5-201"; level 2; protein_id "ENSP00000348704.1"; transcript_support_level "1"; tag "basic"; tag "appris_principal_1"; tag "CCDS"; ccdsid "CCDS5111.1"; havana_gene "OTTHUMG00000015448.4"; havana_transcript "OTTHUMT00000041969.2";
```

After command 3, I used awk command to split the last column using `;`
This is the command

```
command1 input.txt| command2 | command3 | awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{split($NF,a,";"); $NF=""; print $0,a[1],a[4]}'
```

I wanted to split on the last field of the file obtained from command3 and then print all the fields except last field and then a[1] and a[4], the split fields, but this adds a tab between columns 1-25 and a[1],a[4]. How can I avoid that?

Thanks

and this is the output

```
chr6    116732135   116741866   116732135   116732368   116741505   116741866   +   0.79    0.51    0.97    0.77    0.48    0.97    0.02    0.37    'chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.A.withRI','chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.up_chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.dn'    (0,0):10,(1,0):147,(1,1):1  0:148   (0,0):36,(1,0):161,(1,1):3  0:163,1:1   chr6    +   116732136,116732136 116741866,116741866     gene_id "ENSG00000196911.10"     gene_name "KPNA5"
chr6    116732135   116741866   116732135   116732368   116741505   116741866   +   0.79    0.51    0.97    0.77    0.48    0.97    0.02    0.37    'chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.A.withRI','chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.up_chr6:116732136-116732368:+@chr6:116741506-116741866:+.B.dn'    (0,0):10,(1,0):147,(1,1):1  0:148   (0,0):36,(1,0):161,(1,1):3  0:163,1:1   chr6    +   116732136,116732136 116741866,116741866     gene_id "ENSG00000196911.10"     gene_name "KPNA5"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, given

```
$ printf 'foo\tbar\ta;b;c;d' | 
    awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{split($NF,a,";"); $NF=""; print $0,a[1],a[4]}' | cat -A
foo^Ibar^I^Ia^Id$
```

(where I'm using `cat -A` to display the tabs as `^I` for ease of visualization) you want to eliminate the double tab?

If so, one way would be to decrement `NF` instead of assigning the empty string to `$NF`:

```
$ printf 'foo\tbar\ta;b;c;d' | 
    awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{split($NF,a,";"); NF--; print $0,a[1],a[4]}' | cat -A
foo^Ibar^Ia^Id$
```

Another way would be to concatenate the strings instead of printing them as fields - you can do that by removing the `,` between them:

```
$ printf 'foo\tbar\ta;b;c;d' | 
    awk -F "\t" -v OFS="\t" '{split($NF,a,";"); $NF=""; print $0 a[1],a[4]}' | cat -A
foo^Ibar^Ia^Id$
```

Comment: The effect of decrementing `NF` is strictly speaking "undefined" by the POSIX standard, but it may well work in some implementations of `awk`.